# Let {$a_1, a_2, a_3$} be some basis in $R^3$. Does the set of vectors {$b_1, b_2, b_3$} form a basis if

Tags: linear-algebra

a) $b_1$ = $a_1$ x $a_2$, $b_2$ = $a_2$ x $a_3$, $b_3$ = $a_3$ x $a_1$? (cross product)

b) $b_1 = a_1$ x $(a_2$ x $a_3), b_2 = a_2 $x $(a_3$ x $a_1), b_3 = a_3$ x $(a_1$ x$ a_2)$?

I got as far as figuring out that I need $adj(a_1 : a_2 : a_3)$, but I am unsure on how this will show if ${b_1, b_2, b_3}$ will be a basis.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 29 days a member, 7 questions asked...about time you learn the basic directions to properly write mathematics in this site.

Comment: How did you define the multiplicative operation in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: its the cross product